# Interface Design Question

Tags: interface

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168661/javascript-table-manipulation) a while back and basically the project almost consists of reproducing excel in the browser.  We want people to input data in an excel-like way.  The question i have is, what is the best control to use?  Should i use a regular table, and then append columns to it, or should i use a datagrid and flip it XtoY?  What approach would you take?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what technology your using? What do you mean by 'control'?

Comment: Right now I’m prototyping.  I've been told to use any development technology I want.  I've used JavaScript to generate a "<TABLE>"; I’ve used Silverlight Beta 2 and used a "<DataGrid>".  I like Silverlight because it isn't JavaScript.  Creating a "<TABLE>" is JS is hell I do not wish on anyone.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a TON of development time, don't try to do it yourself. Try a 3rd party control like Telerik or ComponentOne.  None will probably have every feature you wish for, but you should be able to find one that is close enough.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Check out the Silverlight option to develop your application. And it had a good Excel like DataGrid which is rendered at the Browser lever and you can have async  calls to server at any point of time you want to persit a change.

Option 2: There are many [datagrids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127647/what-is-the-best-free-datagrid-for-wpf) available in WPF and you can get a high performance application using .NET3.5, and it is possible to host this as XBAP application.

Option 3: Typical ASP.NET with AJAX enabled Datagrid

Comment: Silverlight just doesn't make any sense here, you can easily accomplish this with javascript; simply drop a lightweight ajax datagrid control on the page like Flexigrid for jQuery.

Comment: Silverlight has DataGrid, the benifit is C# language backend which is always better than JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [ExtJS](http://extjs.com) for an [editable data grid](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html) with an AJAX data source. ExtJS is a bit bulky but very flexible.

Comment: +1 for the ExtJS datagrid -- I was going to suggest Flexigrid and jQuery, but that one looks even better.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/). It's a drop in control that mimics (and works with) Excel for .Net. I've seen it used well for both display and back-end calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The Farpoint Spread control emulates Excel grids pretty well, you can even code formulas behind it.  It does cost money though

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the new Datagrid that is in the wpf toolkit on [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf) has what you need. This datagrid can be templated and style the way you need it.