# Create new row code functionality is not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a code to add more row on link. This code is execute on Firefox , Chrome but not on IE-8. Generating error on IE. Error is

```
Unknown runtime error
```

**Code:**

**addmore.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function addrel()
{
var xmlhttp;
    var str1=document.forms["regisration"]["count1"].value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            var taha="reladd"+str1;

            document.getElementById(taha).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
       }

var str=parseInt(document.forms["regisration"]["count1"].value,10);

    xmlhttp.open("GET","addmoreRelative.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    str=str+1;
    document.forms["regisration"]["count1"].value=str;
}
</script>

<form name="regisration" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
         <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="count1" value="1"/>

<table border="0"   > 
    <tr >
        <td><b>Surname</b></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
         <input type="text" name="rlast" id="rlast" maxlength="30" value="" />      
        </td>
         <td> <a href="javascript:void()" onClick="addrel()">Add More</a></td>
    </tr>
        <?php for($t=1;$t<=9;$t++){?><tr id="reladd<?php echo $t; ?>" ></tr><?php }?>
</table>
```

**addmoreRelative.php**

```
    <?php
$count=$_GET['q']; ?>

<td><input type="text" name="rlast<?php echo $count; ?>" id="rlast<?php echo $count; ?>" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Known issue.  Updating *PART* of a table under IE8 and below is simply broken.

You either have to replace the entire table, or you have to use the traditional DOM table manipulation.

See [JavaScript Table Manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168661/javascript-table-manipulation) for hints.